# EA.Element Property CompositeDiagram cannot be set

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

When I try to modify the property using VBScript

```
dim cd as EA.Diagram
...
set currentElement.CompositeDiagram=cd
```

I get 'Unable to write read-only property'

But how come EA is able to set it via elements context-menu in diagram view "New Child Diagram->Select Composite Diagram"...

or in other words, does somebody know how to set the Composite Diagram of an Element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant set the composite diagram in that property .

Use **SetCompositeDiagram** operation instead .

> Parameters:
>   • String - the GUID of the composite diagram.

Refer [EA Online Help](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/automation_and_scripting/element2.html) for more .

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I must have overread this in the documentation